# C VC8 project executable is not executing in machine where vc8 is not installed

Tags: c, compatibility, exe, visual-c++-6, vc8

Executable generated by `vc8` C project (in windows 7) is running in all windows machine (both win xp and 7) in which `vc8` is installed. But its not running in one win xp machine where `vc8` is not installed, but `vc6` is installed. Error message is `System cannot run the executabe`.

Is it happening because my vc8 project is not generating vc6 compatible exe ? Please some one help is there any way to solve this problem.

Note : Creating vc6 project and adding all c files is a complex task, which will take so much time for me.

Comment: Have you installed the C-runtime?

Comment: Is the architecture the same on all your machines? You say `one win xp machine` it doesn't work on, are all of your Win 7/Win XP machines either 32 or 64 bits?

Comment: All of my machine architecture are same and its 32 bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to have visual studio installed to run an application on another machine. Compile in release mode and install the redistributable package on the target machine.

For VC8 (2005):

[VS 2005 x86](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3387)

[VS 2005 x64](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21254)

for other versions just search for c++ redistributable package

EDIT:
If you compile in debug mode you need the debug versions of the runtime library etc. However these are not redistributable. For a workaround (for use on testing machines, not for clients) see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985618%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) for more details.

Comment: So if i compile it on debug mode, it will not work. Is it so?

Comment: for testing see edit above (basically amounts to copying the required debug dlls to the test machine, in the same folder as the executable)

Comment: ya with release mode exe is working with redistributable package.